# jQuery setting input value attribute using .html() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to set the contents of the `value` attribute in the `input` element but have not been successful doing this.

HTML:

```
<div class='photo-info'>
    Photo Name : <span class='photo-name'><?php echo $title; ?></span>
    <span class='title-edit'><a href='#'>Edit</a></span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
// show editable area for title
    $('.title-edit').on('click', function () {
        var $titleElm = $(this).prev();
        var text = $titleElm.text();
        $titleElm.html("<input type='text'>").val('tom');
    })
```

Result:

https://jsfiddle.net/fh7t9qwd/1/

Comment: I would suggest just doing the following $titleElm.html("<input type='text' value='tom'>");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `find('input')` after you update the HTML:

```
$titleElm.html("<input type='text'>").find('input').val('tom');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fh7t9qwd/2/)

Comment: Thanks! The way I was thinking was: `.html()` returns a jquery object so why not chain `.val()` right after. Do you know why it did not work as I had in mind?

Comment: Because `html()` here is returning the jQuery object of `$titleElm` which isn't an `input`. `html()` does not return a jQuery object of the *specified HTML*, but of the outer container itself.